How to handle exception 'ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint' in Spring Boot
i have a table user_asset in PostgreSQL with column id, user_id ,code ( type - integer, constraint - user_asset_code_unique).
user_asset

id  user_id  code
1     97     7752
2     98     7753 
3     99     7754

@Repository
public interface AssetRepository extends JpaRepository<UserAsset, Integer> {}

@Entity
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user_asset", schema = "public")
public class UserAsset {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "code")
    private MPID mpid;
}

private final AssetRepository assetRepository;

@Transactional
public UserAssetResponse update(UserAssetRequest dto){
    //some code here

    User user = userRepository.findById(dto.getID());

    addAssets(user, dto.getAssets());
} 

private void addAssets(User user, List<Long> assets){

    List<UserAsset> newAssets = mpidRepository.findAllById(assets).stream()
            .map(item -> UserAsset.builder().user(user).mpid(item).build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    assetRepository.saveAll(newAssets);
}

From Postman i send:
{
    "id": 97,
    "assets": [7753,7754]
}

As you see from example above the db:
id  user_id  code
1     97     7752

and i try to update [7753,7754] codes
When i try to update UserAssetResponse and set existing code column i got exception.
On Postman i see:
500 Internal server error
{
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [user_asset_code_unique]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}

On IDEA the error is:
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_asset_code_unique"
  Detail: Key (mpid_id)=(7753) already exists.

I understand that it happened because of column code constraint [user_asset_code_unique].
The problem is that i don't know where this exception happened and how to handle this exception .
I try this solution and i know it's wrong to catch Exception but it does not help.
try{
  assetRepository.saveAll(newAssets);          
}catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}


Show the CREATE TABLE statement or complete table definition.

You need to check user_asset_code_unique again. I think this conxtraint should include both user_id and code columns.

I see "transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only" Do you know how to handle this ? I did         try{
portfolioAssetRepository.saveAll(newPortfolioAssets);
}catch (Exception e){
throw new MyException(400, "My message");
}

If you take a look at the stack trace printed out with the exception, that will tell you where the exception originated from. Also, unless the thrown exception is a RuntimeException or some other type of Thorowable other than Exception, then your try-catch block should be capturing it. Have you run it in debug mode with a break point within the catch block?

I see "transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only" Do you know how to handle this ? I did         try{
portfolioAssetRepository.saveAll(newPortfolioAssets);
}catch (Exception e){
throw new MyException(400, "My message");
}
